# Apache Pulsar - ioThreads/listenerThreads and message ordering

Tags: apache-pulsar

We are developing an application that requires messages with the same key to be processed strictly in sequence. In addition, for performance/throughput reasons, we need to introduce parallel processing.

Parallelizing is easy - we can have a single thread receiving the messages, calculating a hash on the key, and use hash % number of workers to distribute the message to a particular blocking queue with a worker on the other side. This guarantees that messages with the same key are dispatched to the same worker, so ordering is guaranteed - as long as the receiver gets the messages in order.

The questions are:

1. Does increasing ioThreads and listenerThreads (default = 1) have an impact on performance, i.e. should we expect to see more messages flowing through or will I/O always be the limiting factor?
2. If we increase them, are we still guaranteed ordering?

The Pulsar documentation is not clear...

Answer (score 2):

> Does increasing ioThreads and listenerThreads (default = 1) have an impact on performance, i.e. should we expect to see more messages flowing through or will I/O always be the limiting factor?

It might, depending on various factors.

1. IoThreads: this is the thread pool used to manage the TCP connections with brokers. If you're producing/consuming across many topics, you'll most likely be interacting with multiple brokers and thus have multiple TCP connections opened. Increasing the ioThreads count might remove the "single thread bottleneck", though it would only be effective if such bottleneck is indeed present (most of the time it will not be the case...). You can check the CPU utilization in your consumer process, across all threads, to see if there's any thread approaching 100% (of a single CPU core).
2. ListenerThreads: this the thread pool size when you are using the message listener in the consumer. Typically this is the thread-pool used by application to process the messages (unless it hops to a different thread). It might make sense to increase the threads count here if the app processing is reaching the 1 CPU core limit.

> If we increase them, are we still guaranteed ordering?

Yes.

- IO threads: 1 TCP connection is always mapped to 1 IO thread
- ListenerThreads: 1 Consumer is assigned to 1 listener thread

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at using the new key-shared subscription type that was introduced in Pulsar 2.4. Per the [documentation](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/concepts-messaging/#key_shared),

> Messages are delivered in a distribution across consumers and message with same key or same ordering key are delivered to only one consumer.